# javascript modify variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

```
var category = "3%2C16%2C6%2C10%2C1%2C19";
```

in witch category id are `3 16 6 10 1 19` and the `%2C` is the space between category.

What i want is here:

```
if (document.getElementById("3").checked = false) {
    category = "16%2C6%2C10%2C1%2C19";
}
else {
    category = "3%2C16%2C6%2C10%2C1%2C19";
}
```

I want to make this for all the checkbox that i have, but you can't deselect all the checkbox because the servers don't send you back any data.

This is for filtering the results

Comment: what are you trying to do? can you explain a little more in detail?

Comment: First: You are using assigning operator in if statement. Second: If you wan't at least one box to be checked why don'y you try using radio boxes in place of check box?

Comment: i'm trying to parse a json,and adding some filters,if you uncheck the checkbox the variable for the id remove the selected id,or if you check it it will add the id

Comment: there are 6 checkbox and the problem is if you uncheck 5 and only one is checked the var category should only contain the id not the %2C

Comment: i can't use radio button because you can have multiply checkbox selected

Comment: You tagged it as jquery - are you using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to use an array, then convert it to this string representation, when needed.

```
var categories = [];
$('#category-form input').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id'),
        index = categories.indexOf(id);
    if (this.checked && index === -1) {
        categories.push(id);
    } else if (!this.checked && index !== -1) {
        categories.splice(index, 1); 
    }
});
```

You can see my working code in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6mexvsc/). 
(with multiple checkboxes, string representation, and at least one check)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if (document.getElementById("3").checked === false) {
```

notice the extra double equals to do a typesafe check

or better still

```
if (!document.getElementById("3").checked) {
```

However, as you're using jQuery and you appear to be munging a string together from checked states, which is going to be really brittle with hardcoded strings so maybe something like:

```
var category = "";

$( "input:checked" ).each(function() {
    category = $(this).id + "%2C";
};
```

Only calling that when you need the output e.g. button press.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using jquery, you can listen to the `change` event for the checkboxes, then build the list each time one is checked or unchecked. To store the values you can either use the `value` attribute for the checkbox or add `data-` attributes.

Getting an array of values and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)ing them will avoid the trailing `%2C`.

```js
var category = '';
(function($) {
    // cache collection of checkboxes
    var cboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');

    cboxes.on('change', function() {
        // find the ticked boxes only, and make an array of their category values, then join the values by a space
        category = $.makeArray(cboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
            return $(this).data('category');
            //return $(this).val(); // if you store them in value="3"
        })).join('%2C');
        
        // output for debug purpose
        $('#categoryOutput').html("'" + category + "'");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1" data-category="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="c2" data-category="16" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="c3" data-category="6" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="c4" data-category="10" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="c5" data-category="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="c6" data-category="19" />
</form>
<div id="categoryOutput"></div>
```

Side Note: try to avoid starting element `id`s with numbers - it is technically invalid and can break things in some scenarios.

Comment: i think this is what i wan't but i don't know why it is now working